# A Badly Punctured Riddle: Stick With It

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> A tabby ate a country lane-
>   And nothing more. Can you explain
>   An edit mark? It may be said
>   A pirate word is found. In bed,
>   Vehicular decay may suit.
>   Incentive is a crunchy root.

The solution is a single English word.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe the word is:

> CARROT

"A Badly Punctured Riddle: Stick With It"

> Reference to Carrot and Stick perhaps? As motivation? Edit: Probably not correct, but is 'Badly Punctured' perhaps referring to the letters "A,R,R,O" which have 'holes' in them?

A tabby ate a country lane-
And nothing more. Can you explain

> Tabby is an orange coloured cat. The word CArroT is surrounding by the word Cat- reference to the tabby 'eating' something. Country lane can be 'rural road' or RR. Add nothing i.e. "O" So CAT eats RRO. (Thanks Tom!)

An edit mark? It may be said

> A ^ is an edit mark named "Caret", a homophone of carrot

A pirate word is found. In bed,

> A pirate word "arr" found in bed, a "cot"

Vehicular decay may suit.

> Car - Rot

Incentive is a crunchy root.

> Carrot on a stick is a phrase for an incentive. Carrot is a crunchy root.

Comment: RRO may be = RR (Rural Route) + O (and nothing more)

Comment: Add in Tom's comment and you get the tick. Mention the title and make me happy. :-)

Comment: I can't explain "badly punctured" but "stick with it" might also be a reference to "carrot on a stick" - "stick with carrot [on the end]"

Comment: @F1Krazy I've never in my life heard of a "carrot on a stick". Are you thinking of the idiom "carrot and stick" referring to a situation in which somebody is simultaneously encouraged to do something and threatened with consequences if they don't?

Comment: @DavidRicherby The phrase carrot on a stick is meant to signify something you want dangling out in front of you, usually as an incentive. While it's not relevant to this, Minecraft literally uses the phrase as riding a pig while holding a 'carrot on a stick' will allow you to direct the pig as he is trying to reach the desired item (carrot) but it keeps dangling out in front of him, no matter how much he moves towards it.

Comment: @n_palum Hmm. That sounds a lot like somebody, at some point, either misunderstood the idiom "carrot and stick" or made it more PC by repurposing the stick.

Comment: @DavidRicherby "Carrot on a stick is a similar, but separate, idiom. It refers to a policy of offering a reward for making progress towards benchmarks or goals but not necessarily ever actually delivering." - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrot_and_stick

Answer (score 6):

The answer is

> CARROT.

*A tabby ate a country lane-*
*And nothing more. Can you explain*

> A **CAT** ate a **RRO** (which maybe means "country lane" somehow?)

*An edit mark? It may be said*

> [Caret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret) is a synonym ("may be said").

*A pirate word is found. In bed,*

> **ARR** is found in **COT**.

*Vehicular decay may suit.*

> **CAR** **ROT**.

*Incentive is a crunchy root.*

> A carrot is a crunchy root, and can be used metaphorically as incentive.

Comment: http://www.homophone.com/h/carat-caret-carrot-karat It *is* metaphorically an incentive